# Python 3.7: asyncio.run_in_executor() returns RuntimeError "There is no current event loop error"

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn asyncio and am working to write a class for connecting to the Alpaca Market API so I can do further work. I wanted to connect to two different parts of the API asynchronously just to see if I could use asyncio correctly. I used asyncio.run_in_executor() because connecting is not an awaitable function. It appears as though the program is running the two coroutines asynchronously but the second coroutine is failing because there is no thread even though I set the default executor to ThreadPoolExecutor(2). Below is what I've got so far, plus the output to the terminal.

```
import os, sys, re
from typing import Union

import csv
import asyncio
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import alpaca_trade_api as alpaca
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time



class DataHouse:

    def __init__(self, env=None):
        self._env = None
        self._conn = None
        self._rest = None
        self._env_keys = ['key_id','secret_key','base_url','data_url','data_stream']
        self._api_keys = dict()


        if self._env is not None:
            load_dotenv(self._env)
            for key in self._env_keys:
                val = os.getenv(key).strip()
                if val is None:
                    raise ValueError(f"Missing {key} value in .env file")
                self._api_keys[key] = val

        async def consume_responses(*coro, loop):
            result = await asyncio.gather(*coro, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)
            print(result)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(2))
        coros = [self.rest(loop), self.conn(loop)]
        loop.run_until_complete(consume_responses(*coros, loop=loop))

    def get_rest(self):
        return self._rest
    def get_conn(self):
        return self._conn

    async def rest(self, loop, executor=None):
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.rest_connect)
    def rest_connect(self):
        print("REST BEGIN")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("REST END")
        return alpaca.rest.REST(**{key: self._api_keys[key] for key in self._env_keys[:2]}, api_version='v2')

    async def conn(self, loop, executor=None):
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.conn_connect)
    def conn_connect(self):
        print("CONN BEGIN")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("CONN END")
        return alpaca.stream2.StreamConn(**self._api_keys)


    @property
    def env(self):
        return self._env
    @env.setter
    def env(self, env):
        if isinstance(env, str) and re.search(r'\.env$', env) is not None:
            self._env = env
        else:
            raise ValueError("the DataHouse env variable must be set to the *.env string to the file containing API information. env = str(path_to_env.env)")
```

I then test it by running

```
import DataHouse

test = DataHouse('paper_env.env')
```

And the output I get is

```
REST BEGIN
CONN BEGIN
CONN CONNECTED
REST CONNECTED
[<alpaca_trade_api.rest.REST object at 0x000002A133DFD668>, RuntimeError("There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1'.")]
```

The print statements occurred asynchronously, so that's good, and I was able to get the first API connection, but the result of the second connection is a RuntimeError and I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.